# How to Update with condition from Cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using Mysql to Update with condition from a Cursor.
For example I have below query:

```
declare cur1 cursor for select id from User;
```

then I want to loop update with condition each `id`

```
loop
Update User set name = 'XXXXXXX'
where id = @id --> id from cursor
end loop
```

How to write this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even see why you need to/should use a cursor here.  A regular update should achieve the same thing:

```
UPDATE User
SET name = 'XXXXXXX';
```

Having a `WHERE` clause in an update is a good thing, but your `WHERE` clause would just include all records anyway.  Assuming the `id` values were coming from a different table, you could use an update join, something like this:

```
UPDATE User u
INNER JOIN Other o
    ON u.id = o.id
SET name = 'XXXXXXX';
```

Comment: hi. thx u, but the query is just for sample, i want to update other user table base on value cursor

Comment: You are missing the point of my answer, which is that you probably don't need to even use a cursor here.

Comment: im got it, but i have query with many join,
if i use 
UPDATE User u
INNER JOIN Other o
    ON u.id = o.id
SET name = 'XXXXXXX';
it take long time event i limit it by 1,
but if i add condition 
UPDATE User u
INNER JOIN Other o
    ON u.id = o.id
SET name = 'XXXXXXX'
where u.id = 1
,it running faster
,I use that query just for simplify example